# Updating multiple output lines

Tags: python

So I am trying to use `sys.stdout.write()` to rewrite the current line it is on and replace it with different text. But I want this to happen for multiple lines of output.

```
  # I am looking at having 2 lines with changing values in them that will keep over writing themselves without moving any further down.
  import sys
  for i in range(10):
       sys.stdout.write("\r" + "Hello" + str(i) + "\n + "Hello" + str(i) * 2)
       sys.stdout.flush()
```

I tried this but every time it hits the \n it will indefinately increase the numbers of lines without clearing everything.

Comment: (Don't worry about marking your post as "not urgent" - nothing is urgent here anyway, so I've trimmed it).

Answer (score 2):

stdout\stderr don't work like that. You can send control characters to your terminal to delete characters but once a line is sent it's basically fixed.

What you actually need is [ncurses](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/curses.html) which gives you much more control over the display and cursor position when writing to a terminal.