# Updating multiple lines of perl output on terminal

Tags: perl, printing, printf

I am trying to update the progress of my Perl script on the terminal. The output looks something like this

> ```
>   Progress: |||||||||            [46%]
> ```

The progress keeps on getting updated until it reaches 100%. This is being done by printing "\r" after updating the progress. I wish to update multiple lines at the same time, how can it be done? The expectation is something like this

> ```
>   Progress: |||||||||            [46%]
>   Run-time: 100sec
> ```

After some progress(and or time) I wish to update it like this

> ```
>   Progress: ||||||||||           [50%]
>   Run-time: 150sec
> ```

I tried printing "\r" two times to go to the previous line. But it didn't work.

I found similar questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41999044/updating-multiple-output-lines) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840420/rewrite-multiple-lines-in-the-console)), but they were answered for Python using modules. Mine is a Perl script, and I am not preferring to use external modules.

Comment: The [Curses](https://metacpan.org/pod/Curses) library is also available to Perl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Term::ANSIScreen](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::ANSIScreen) provides terminal control using ANSI escape sequences:

```
use Term::ANSIScreen qw!savepos loadpos!;

print savepos();
for my $i (1..10) {
    print '|' x $i, "\n";
    print "Step: $i\n";
    sleep 1;
    print loadpos();
}
```

or

```
use Term::ANSIScreen qw!up!;

for my $i (1..10) {
    print '|' x $i, "\n";
    print "Step: $i\n";
    sleep 1;
    print up(2);
}
```

These constants can be used instead of the module:

```
my $savepos = "\e[s";
my $loadpos = "\e[u";
my $up2 = "\e[2A";
```

[ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)

Comment: The general approach is solid, but `savepos`/`loadpos` doesn't work for me either. (It appears to only save/restore the X position, as you can see using `print "abc", savepos(), "def\n", loadpos(), "ghi\n";`.) I've added an alternative that works. (@toolic)

Comment: (Tip: Always remember to print something at least as long as the message being overwritten or you can get garbage. Spaces can be used to erase. Shouldn't be a problem for the OP.)

Comment: hey UjinT34 and @ikegami, thank you for adding your answers. Sorry for sounding finicky, but I do not wish to use any external modules. (Moreover, I'm working in a little restricted environment where I can't install any modules). Is there a direct way to jump back two lines without using any modules? I believe there must be some way to do it without modules. Thank you.

Comment: `Term::ANSIScreen` returns ansi escape sequences. You can copy them to your script.

Comment: Thank you @UjinT34. Escape sequences did the job. This is exactly what I've been looking for.